# Having trouble on this assignment where we need to use pointers and arrays to find the average, median, and mode of some numbers in a text file

Tags: c++

I'm having some issues when trying to read in the values from a text file. The text file looks like this:

```
Murray Brandl 3 
Christal Delamater 4
Zetta Kinlaw 7
Elia Roy 3
Delmer Bibb 4
Joannie Nevers 4
Roselle Gose 10
Jonathan Basnett 0
Marcel Earwood 12
Marina Newton 2
Magdalen Stephan 3
Deane Leach 5
Mariana Crosley 6
Darby Froman 5
Shonda Kyzer 4
Ilana Netto 4
Candida Magnani 1
Laurena Stiverson 2
Elouise Muir 4
Rene Holiday 2
```

We need to read these names and values into variables while using pointers and arrays. I am getting some errors such as this:

"Exception thrown: read access violation.
**_Pnext** was 0xFDFDFE01. occurred"

I don't know what this means or where to look to fix it. Below you can see my attempt so far, but I've only gotten to the averageMovie function because I am unable to read the text file in correctly. If you could help me out or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "Chapter 10 Movie Statistics.h"

using namespace std;

void averageMovie(int [], int);

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("MovieStatistics.txt");

    int numOfStudents = 0;
    string first, last, line;
    int movies;

    int *numMovies;
    string *names;

    numMovies = new int[numOfStudents];
    names = new string[numOfStudents];

    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file";
    }
    else
    {
        while (getline(infile, line))
        {
            numOfStudents++;

            istringstream ss(line);

            ss >> first >> last >> movies;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)
        {
            names[i] = first + last;
            numMovies[i] = movies;
        }
    }


    cout << "The number of students in the file is: " << numOfStudents << endl << endl;

    averageMovie(numMovies, numOfStudents);

    return 0;
}

void averageMovie(int array[], int size)
{
    int total = 0,
        average;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        total += array[i];
    }

    average = total / size;

    cout << "The average number of movies watched is: " << average;
}
```

Comment: When you create `numMovies` and `names`, what is the value of `numOfStudents`? You do know that the program will not retroactively go back and redo those allocations after the loop?

Comment: Don't allocate arrays with `new`, use `std::vector`. Every time you see a pointer in your code, think that there is something wrong.

Comment: You are trying to do too many new things at once. If you are required to use arrays, play around with arrays (of ints) until you can put elements into an array and read them out with no errors. Get that working before you try to read numbers from a file into an array. Play with strings, and storing `string*` in an array; get *that* working before you try to mate it to file input. Don't bother with calculating averages until all of that works perfectly.

Comment: @Beta: Don't ever store `string*` in an array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I hadn't planned to, but-- why not (apart from aesthetics)?

Comment: @Beta: Because it's an indicator that your program probably has terribly unclear ownership semantics and is therefore highly error-prone. It's a sign of a poor/weak/fragile design. There are times when you want to store pointers in a container, but they are almost always indexes into other containers (for implementing various algorithms) and I can't think of very many situations when you'd use an array for that. Beyond that, strings are values and should be treated like such. The most basic cause for storing `string*` is that you wrote `new string` which is just... wrong.

Comment: @Beta: If you hadn't planned to store `string*` in an array, I'm curious what you were referring to when you suggested that the OP do it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I too dislike its aesthetics, I am aware of the dangerous implications of storing pointers in an array, and the `string*[]` was the OP's idea.

Comment: @Beta: I don't see a `string*[]` anywhere other than your comment :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: My mistake, the OP wrote `string * = new string[]`. The basic idea of my first comment still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numOfStudents = 0;
// [snip]
int *numMovies;
string *names;
// [snip]
numMovies = new int[numOfStudents];
names = new string[numOfStudents];
```

Both of your arrays have zero elements; thus, every single access to them is broken. Increasing `numOfStudents` later makes no difference; it is too late.

What you're seeing is the technical result of utterly blasting your computer's memory.

Options:

1. Pick a number (e.g. 100) and use that; use *up to* 100 slots; stop the program before you go over that limit, though!
2. Precalculate how many you will actually need (one per line in the file, right?), *then* allocate the arrays
3. Use an array that expands on its own, i.e. a *vector* (though I'm betting your assignment does not permit this)

Comment: Oh wow, what a simple mistake. Can't believe I didn't realize this earlier. Anyway, thanks for your help!